# Can a racist business owner legally get away with saying he only wants to hire people that 'look white'?

Tags: united-states, employment, discrimination, bfoq

This is a belated follow up to an [earlier](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/65097/is-it-illegal-for-me-to-refuse-to-hire-a-white-child-actor-because-the-already-s) question where I asked how one can get away with hiring actors of an appropriate race when  BFOQ (Bona Fide Occupational Qualifications) exceptions do not apply to race.  The answer was that you can't insist on hiring someone who *is* black, but you can require someone that looks black.

So taking that to the logical extreme if one employer is allowed to make requirements based off of one's apparent race why can't others?  If I have some organization that panders to racist folks can I say I need all my servers to look like the appropriate race so that I don't offend my clientele?

I'm pretty sure (and hope!) the answer is that this isn't legal, but what I'm wondering is more what the distinction between these two cases is.  How is the line drawn between the few legitimate reasons where hiring someone based off of the race they appear to be makes sense and all the numerous occasions where it would just be an end-run around refusing to hire someone based off of race?  Is there an actual hard and fast line here?  Has there been a court case where someone tried to hire only people that appear white as a means of discrimination and the courts gave a ruling specifying why it wasn't allowed?

Comment: I think it depends on what position the person is hiring for as hiring a model can have different requirements then hiring waitstaff at a restaurant.

Comment: "If I have some organization that panders to racist folks" - I can only assume that this stance has to have been documented in the business proposal to the local ordinance and I doubt "The KKK Experience" is something that gets approved except for in the most racist cities across America.

Comment: I wonder if an athletics coach lost his job because he could not coach the 800 meters if the courts would consider race-ial discrimination?

Comment: These questions always make me wonder:  Craigslist is full of ads for "cleaning lady"; can I sue them because I'm a good cleaner but don't fit the gender demanded in the job description?

Comment: @B.Goddard you couldnt' sue craigslist because it's not responsible for adds put up by people using their service, web 2,0 services like it and facebook etc are given protections so that a random user posting something on their website doesn't make them liable for that persons behaviors.  It would be hard to find, much less get anything useful out of, the random individual on craigs list who made the post.  Besides that I imagine one can claim that 'cleaning lady' was just a bad description and they were open to all genders since it didn't explicitly say no men.

Comment: @dsollen  I meant suing the advertiser.  There are ads that say "female care giver for elderly woman." And "If you are a female and want to write reviews about intimate products...."  There's no mistake there what gender they want.

Comment: @B.Goddard the later is justified since presumably the 'intimate products' in question require certain body parts to properly try out and test the products (though I think it would be amusing for a trans women to try answering one of those adds...).  I'll give you the former as a legitimate question I'm not qualified to answer.

Comment: Is the question about the difference between “people who look white” and “people who are white”?, which is not 100% the same?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No.

The Civil Rights Act of 1964 prohibits an employer from discriminating on the basis of  race, color, religion, sex, or national origin. It is therefore generally forbidden for an employer to refuse to hire someone because they are not white/black/etc. or because they do not look white/black/etc.

The law permits exceptions when the employee's religion, sex, or national origin is a bona fide occupational qualifiction, but not when the employee's race or color is a bona fide occupational qualification.

The answer to your previous question was wrong because it adopts an "is black vs. looks black" distinction that doesn't really work. Discriminating against someone because they "look black" is the same thing as discriminating on the basis of color. Even if you were saying someone "looked black" because of their hair or facial structure or clothing, you're talking about "perceived as" discrimination, which many courts treat as equally impermissible. See, e.g., [*Perkins v. Lake Cty.*, 860 F. Supp. 1262, 1278 (N.D. Ohio 1994)](https://casetext.com/case/perkins-v-lake-county-dept) (“Objective appearance and employer perception are the basis for discrimination and, in the opinion of this Court, the key factors relevant to enforcing rights granted members of a protected class.”).

As far as I know, the question of whether one may discriminate on the basis of race or color in casting decisions is still unresolved, but the courts that have looked at it seem to so far be in agreement that casting directors may make engage in that kind of discrimination because their constitutional rights to create their art as they see fit under the First Amendment overrides their statutory obligation to provide equal employment opportunities under the Civil Rights Act.

For example, the issue arose when a black man brought civil-rights claims against ABC for excluding him from auditions for *The Bachelor*. ABC argued that its casting decisions are an essential component of its expression, and the court agreed:

> Ultimately, whatever messages The Bachelor and The Bachelorette communicate or are intended to communicate — whether explicitly, implicitly, intentionally, or otherwise — the First Amendment protects the right of the producers of these Shows to craft and control those messages, based on whatever considerations the producers wish to take into account. ... Thus, whether enforcing § 1981 here would frustrate, enhance, or be entirely consistent with the message that The Bachelor and The Bachelorette conveys, the First Amendment protects the producers' right unilaterally to control their own creative content.

[*Claybrooks v. ABC, Inc.*, 898 F. Supp. 2d 986, 1000 (M.D. Tenn. 2012)](https://casetext.com/case/claybrooks-v-am-broad-cos-inc).

Comment: I think there was a theater playing Othello with the guy playing Othello being the only white one - all other actors were black.

Comment: @gnasher729 I suppose it was intended like this by the stage director, not because they couldn't refuse to take white/black actors for the respective roles.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, that was intentional. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race-reversed_casting

Comment: @gnasher729 I believe Patrick Stewart did that.

Comment: There is also the case of Gershwin. He made almost exclusively use of african-American actors in his musicals. Still to this day you are unlikely to find a rendition of porgy and Bess without a mainly black cast.

Answer (score 11):

In the case of an actor, the actor's appearance, even the actor's detailed appearance, is pretty clearly a BFOQ. The actor must fit the director's (or producer's) vision of the role, and fit into the rest of the cast visually (or stand out in the way wanted for the particular production.) For example, in a traditional production of *Othello* the actor must look Black.  In a crime drama set in inner-city Los Angles, the actor must seem to fit that setting, and quite possible must look Hispanic, depending on the details of the drama and role.

This is not true for most occupations. The employer has no **legitimate** interest in how a truck driver or cook looks. While there is some superficial plausibility in the "my customers won't accept a server of XX race" claim, I believe it has been held that this makes unlawful racial discrimination by the owner too easy, and this has been held not to be a BFOQ.

Comment: BFOQ's don't apply here since the BFOQ cannot apply to race, at least that's how I understand the law?

Comment: @dsollen Appearance can, in special circumstances, be a BFOQ. Even racial appearance as in "looks black". It may be that in some very limited circumstances race can.

Comment: Appearance may or may not be a BFOQ, but it definitely isn't among the BFOQs that the Civil Rights Act accepts as an exception. I think OP correctly highlights the problem with the answers to both of his questions.

Comment: @dsollen part of the problem here is that "black" means more than one thing, even if you consider only the senses related to race and ethnicity.

Comment: @DavidSiegel can you back up your claim that appearance can be used as a BFOQ exception with any specific laws or court cases?

Comment: And even in such cases, appearance matters far more than race.  For example, a tanned Catherine Zeta-Jones did such a convincing job of playing Elena in *The Mask of Zorro* that many people are surprised to learn that she is Welsh and does not have a drop of Hispanic blood in her body.

Comment: @dsollen: [Here's a lead](https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/guidance/cm-625-bona-fide-occupational-qualifications#_ftn3).

Comment: @MasonWheeler in the first season of 24 Arnold Vosloo played an Arab terrorist while being completely Caucasian in real life.

Comment: Then again it took the drama profession a while before female roles where auctually played by women. There is precedent of female roles being played by men, although that is not the modern way.

Comment: @NeilMeyer unlike Noh theater, where it is not acceptable for any woman to be on stage, the Greek theater opened up to women when the Romans came.

Answer (score 5):

They can get away with it, but in the US, at least, it strongly indicates a violation of the Civil Rights Act. A non-racist business owner can also lose a Title VII suit, since the Civil Rights Act isn't used to convict people of racism; rather it protects people from discriminatory hiring practices, which may be subjective.

Notably, the opposite scenario to what is often assumed can also happen; if a business owner or government manager refuses to hire/promote someone because they are "white" the law may also punish that employer. This can happen regardless of whether the employer is also white, or is black, etc. It can also happen if the employer has what they consider good intentions--for example, if they want to give black job applicants a chance at a job.

This is possible simply because when they decide not to hire or promote the (majority) applicant based on race or color, they are violating the act. Minorities are not exclusively protected by the act, *people* are protected, and what they are protected from in this case is "discrimination based on race or color." So it is the act of discriminatory hiring *based on* race, sex, etc., that triggers the law.

Now BFOQ... there are of course some exceptions. A Shinto priest can not force an Apostolic monastic order to hire them as chief abbot, regardless of how qualified they may be in Shinto. Their qualifications as a religious leader are irrelevant in this case because the Apostolic set of beliefs and practices is "essential" to the operation and purpose of an Apostolic monastic order.

You might also be familiar with Hooters, a restaurant which is known for using fertility signals to attract male customers. They were indeed sued by some men who they refused to hire as servers, and they settled the suit. They didn't actually lose it though. What they did was agree to make available a number of gender neutral positions for employment. They preserved the right to select servers based on the signals of attraction considered essential to the business.

And of course there are acting roles, which are somewhat easier to defend under the bona fide occupational qualifications. I'm sure there either is or will be an exception somewhere, some day, but it's not going to be easy to sue someone for refusing to hire a light skinned person for the role of a person who was discriminated against for their dark skin. Or a dark skinned person for the role of an albino for that matter. There are some cases where inborn physical characteristics such as color *are* an essential job qualification. But at the same time, plaintiffs and courts, much less law and administrative code, will likely never define every situation where that is deemed legitimate, vs the situations where it is deemed unfair and illegal discrimination.

See:

- EOCC v. Hooters
- Duvant v. Novant Health

Also:

- Religious exceptions [as described on EOCC guidance](https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/guidance/section-12-religious-discrimination#h_4393287411421610748699300).
- Article discussing and citing cases of [restaurants and adult businesses](https://www.siop.org/Research-Publications/TIP/TIP-Back-Issues/2017/January/ArtMID/20301/ArticleID/1624/Really-I-Come-Here-for-The-Food-Sex-as-a-BFOQ-for-Restaurant-Servers).
- EOCC FAQ about protection for [white employees](https://www.eeoc.gov/youth/racecolor-discrimination-faqs#Q6).
- Discriminating against [your own race](https://www.eeoc.gov/youth/racecolor-discrimination-faqs#Q2).

Comment: In South Africa it is also an accepted that requiring a priest to be religious is not discriminatory. Requiring the churchs bookkeeper to be religious on the other hand is.

Comment: As I understand it hooters is generally agreed to be violating the law by selecting only female waitresses.  They get away with it because they settle any cases where someone claims discrimination and just write off the cost of settling cases as cost of doing business.

Comment: I don't think it's ever been fully litigated, but Hooters takes the position that it operates under the same rules that permit a casting director to hire only white actors for white roles, i.e., its waitresses are not just waitresses but entertainers.

Comment: @bdb484: IIRC Southwest previously tried an iteration of that argument for its flight attendants, and the court was not impressed.

Comment: @Kevin Arguably Southwest has no special business interest in providing sex appeal, aviation tradition aside. But if they were to rebrand as e.g. Tits on Wings then they might have a case. Consider the name Hooters is a euphemism for breasts.

Comment: @dotancohen: At the time, they were explicitly targeting male businessmen with sex appeal, by trying to only hire young and attractive flight attendants. It wasn't just a "tradition," it was a full-blown business strategy.

Comment: @Kevin I see. If there were other aspects to the strategy, such as suggestive advertising or livery, then I could imagine there being a case. If Hooters could be a "breasteraunt", then surely Southwest could pioneer "The **wings**, and the **breasts**".

Comment: @dotancohen Interestingly, SW was calling themselves "The Love Airline" and dressing stewardesses in hot pants. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_v_Southwest_Airlines_Co for good description. They did get a judgement against them in US District Court for N Texas. For Hooters, if someone sees litigation through, they might get a judgement for the same reason, who knows. Avoiding a case that goes all the way is probably a thing for them right now, but if it ever does, expect Amicus briefs from restaurants, adult clubs, casinos, sexy phone hotlines and similar interests.

Comment: @Rab: It seems that Southwest based out of Love Field, which according to Wikipedia is named for a military aviator named Love. So "The Love Airline" theme gets a bit complicated.